# Knowing the position of an object at different times, can we figure out the possible shapes of spacetime and object's trajectory?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, geodesics

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to apply general relativity to determine the probable future locations of an object.

After seeing this excellent illustration of geodesics, it made me think that it indeed should be possible.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfqrCdAjiks

If we observe that an object is moving through a particular path and due to changing mass that the spacetime has its shape given at a specific time, knowing that this object is moving through its worldline in a geodesic, can we determine what the possible shapes are or it's potential limits of the object's future location? If so, what calculations could help determine that?

Comment: The geodesics equation is what you want here, solving it yields the parameterized geodesic of an object.

Comment: @Triatticus would you mind giving an example or a link to a site that explains it well? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't practice cosmology/general relativity, the best I could do is point you first to Wikipedia on geodesics and then to any number of the GR books that exist. But I haven't seen many example calculations of it myself as it can get very difficult depending on the spacetime with your only hope to probably numerically solve it for complicated backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Triatticus. What do you mean by "numerically solve it for complicated backgrounds"?

Comment: Well finding exact solutions is only possible for easy geometries (much like the metric solutions to Einstein's feild equations), otherwise you're stuck with numerically solving it like one would with other differential equations, it's just a more complicated differential equation.